# Looking for a more concise way to put a C# setter into a Dictionary<> for mapping

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

This is a representation of a larger bit of code I’m working on that’s a mapper.  Originally it was written as a large `switch` statement, but I prefer to make the mapping stand out as a table rather than a long, long `switch`.

My first pass looks something like this (from LINQPad):

```
    Dictionary<string, Action<Foobar, decimal>> map
        = new Dictionary<string, Action<Foobar, decimal>> {
                { "one", (f,d) => f.One = d },
                { "double", (f,d) => f.Two = d },
                { "tricycle", (f,d) => f.Three = d },
        };
    
    void Main()
    {
        Foobar obj = new Foobar();
        decimal amount = 100M;
        var x = map["one"];
        x(obj, amount);
    
        Console.WriteLine(obj.One);   // Prints 100 as expected
    }
    public class Foobar
    {
        public decimal One { get; set; }
        public decimal Two { get; set; }
        public decimal Three { get; set; }
    }
```

The real `Foobar` class is large, has many properties, but they’re all the same type: `decimal`.

What I’m looking for is a more concise way of expressing the table above.  This is fine:

```
{ "one", (f,d) => f.One = d },          // It works, but … can it be better?
```

I really *don’t* want to do it as strings with full-on reflection in the invocation:

```
{ "one", "One" },                       // No
{ "one", nameof(Foobar.One) },          // Really, just no.
```

I seem to remember there’s a more concise way to do it, but my Google-fu fails me.  I can get to the *getter* more concisely by changing the signature to `Dictionary<string, Func<Foobar, decimal>>` and then doing this:

```
   { "one", f.One }                        // The getter, not the setter.
```

but that doesn’t get me to the *setter*.  Ideas?

Comment: What you wrote looks almost like an indexer, or an attempt to use dynamic invocation without using `dynamic` or inheriting from `DynamicObject`. You could use `x["tricycle"]=100M` or `x.tricycle=100M`. Either would be cheaper in performance than the action dictionary

Comment: You could get the setter with something like `(Action<Foobar, decimal>)typeof(Foobar).GetProperty("One").SetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Foobar, decimal>))` but it isn't more coincise

Answer (score 1):

You can define your mapping like this:

```
Mapping<Foobar, decimal> foobarMapping = new Mapping<Foobar, decimal> 
{
    { "one", f => f.One },
    { "double", f => f.Two },
    { "tricycle", f => f.Three },
};

public class Foobar
{
    public decimal One { get; set; }
    public decimal Two { get; set; }
    public decimal Three { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    Foobar obj = new Foobar();
    obj.One = 100M;
    
    foobarMapping[obj, "one"].Dump();
    
    foobarMapping[obj, "tricycle"] = 400M;
    obj.Three.Dump();
}

class Mapping<TFrom, TTo>: IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, PropertyInfo>>
{
    Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> mapping = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
    
    public void Add(string name, Expression<Func<TFrom, TTo>> mappingFunction) =>
        mapping.Add(name, (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)mappingFunction.Body).Member);
        
    public TTo this[TFrom from, string key]
    {
        get => (TTo)mapping[key].GetValue(from);
        set => mapping[key].SetValue(from, value);
    }
        
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, PropertyInfo>> GetEnumerator() =>
        mapping.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Which outputs, as expected:

```
100
400
```